# dbutils.secrets.get- NoSuchElementException: None.get

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

The below code executes a 'get' api method to retrieve objects from s3 and write to the data lake.

The problem arises when I use dbutils.secrets.get to get the keys required to establish the connection to s3

```
my_dataframe.rdd.foreachPartition(partition => {
        val AccessKey = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "ADB_Scope", key = "AccessKey-ID")
        val SecretKey = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "ADB_Scope", key = "AccessKey-Secret") 
        val creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(AccessKey, SecretKey)
        val clientRegion: Regions = Regions.US_EAST_1
        val s3client  = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
        .withRegion(clientRegion)
        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds))
        .build()
          partition.foreach(x => {
            val objectKey = x.getString(0)
            val i = s3client.getObject(s3bucketName, objectKey).getObjectContent
            val inputS3String = IOUtils.toString(i, "UTF-8")
            val filePath = s"${data_lake_get_path}"
            val file = new File(filePath)
            val fileWriter = new FileWriter(file)
            val bw = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter)
            bw.write(inputS3String)
            bw.close()
            fileWriter.close()
          })
      })
```

The above results in the error:-

```
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:529)
at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:527)
at com.databricks.dbutils_v1.impl.SecretUtilsImpl.sc$lzycompute(SecretUtilsImpl.scala:24)
at com.databricks.dbutils_v1.impl.SecretUtilsImpl.sc(SecretUtilsImpl.scala:24)
at com.databricks.dbutils_v1.impl.SecretUtilsImpl.getSecretManagerClient(SecretUtilsImpl.scala:36)
at com.databricks.dbutils_v1.impl.SecretUtilsImpl.getBytesInternal(SecretUtilsImpl.scala:46)
at com.databricks.dbutils_v1.impl.SecretUtilsImpl.get(SecretUtilsImpl.scala:61)
```

When the actual secret scope values for AccessKey and SecretKey are passed the above code works fine.

How can this work using dbutils.secrets.get so that keys are not exposed in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move following two lines:

```scala
val AccessKey = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "ADB_Scope", key = "AccessKey-ID")
val SecretKey = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "ADB_Scope", key = "AccessKey-Secret")
```

outside of the `foreachPartition` block, so these functions will be executed in context of driver, and sent to the worker nodes.